# CamShift + Face detection in OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, face-detection, video-tracking

I'm currently combing two examples from OpenCv which let you detect your face and track object. The purpose is to first detect the face and then track it.

My code currently :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import video
import math

cascade = 0
counter = 0

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, video_src):
        self.cam = video.create_capture(video_src)
        ret, self.frame = self.cam.read()
        cv2.namedWindow('camshift')

        self.selection = None
        self.drag_start = None
        self.tracking_state = 0
        self.show_backproj = False


    def show_hist(self):
        bin_count = self.hist.shape[0]
        bin_w = 24
        img = np.zeros((256, bin_count*bin_w, 3), np.uint8)
        for i in xrange(bin_count):
            h = int(self.hist[i])
            cv2.rectangle(img, (i*bin_w+2, 255), ((i+1)*bin_w-2, 255-h), (int(180.0*i/bin_count), 255, 255), -1)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
        cv2.imshow('hist', img)

    '''
    @param: img the image for the face detection
    @param: cascade the cascade of the ViolaJones face detection
    @return: rects, an array of the cornors of the detected face. [x1 y1 x2 y2]
    '''
    def detect(self,img, cascade):

        # Detect the faces
        rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=3, minSize=(150, 150), flags = cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE)

        # Check if any faces are detected
        if len(rects) == 0:

            # return empty array
            return []
        else:
            # Get the correct x and y values
            rects[:,2:] += rects[:,:2]

            # loop over the recs and shrink the width with 40%
            for rec in rects:
                rec[0] = rec[0] + int(math.floor(((rec[2] - rec[0])*0.4)/2))
                rec[2] = rec[2] - int(math.floor(((rec[2] - rec[0])*0.4)/2))

            return rects

    def draw_rects(self,img, rects, color):
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)


    def getFace(self,img):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

        rects = self.detect(gray, cascade)
        self.rects = rects
        img = self.draw_rects(img, rects, (0, 255, 0))

        if len(rects) != 0:
            self.selection = rects[0][1], rects[0][0], rects[0][3], rects[0][2]

        return rects


    def run(self):
        counter= 0
        rects = None
        while True:
            counter +=1;
            ret, self.frame = self.cam.read()
            vis = self.frame.copy()

            if counter % 150 == 0:
                rects = self.getFace(vis);

            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array((0., 60., 32.)), np.array((180., 255., 255.)))
            if rects is not None:
                self.draw_rects(vis, rects, (0, 255, 0))

            if self.selection:
                print 'test0'
                x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.selection
                self.track_window = (x0, y0, x1-x0, y1-y0)
                hsv_roi = hsv[x0:x1,y0:y1]
                mask_roi = mask[x0:x1,y0:y1]
                hist = cv2.calcHist( [hsv_roi], [0], mask_roi, [16], [0, 180] )
                cv2.normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX);
                self.hist = hist.reshape(-1)
                self.show_hist()

                vis_roi = vis[x0:x1,y0:y1]
                cv2.bitwise_not(vis_roi, vis_roi)
                vis[mask == 0] = 0
                self.tracking_state = 1
                self.selection = None



            if self.tracking_state == 1:
                self.selection = None
                prob = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], self.hist, [0, 180], 1)
                prob &= mask
                term_crit = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1 )
                track_box, self.track_window = cv2.CamShift(prob, self.track_window, term_crit)

                if self.show_backproj:
                    vis[:] = prob[...,np.newaxis]
                try: cv2.ellipse(vis, track_box, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                except: print track_box
            cv2.imshow('camshift', vis)


            ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(5)
            if ch == 27:
                break
            if ch == ord('b'):
                self.show_backproj = not self.show_backproj
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, getopt

    args, video_src = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['cascade=', 'nested-cascade='])
    try: video_src = video_src[0]
    except: video_src = 0
    args = dict(args)
    cascade_fn = args.get('--cascade', "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade_fn)

    App(video_src).run()
```

Currently I show where the face was initially (in a green rectangle) and what is tracked at  the moment (in a red oval). I am able to detect the face, but the face tracker keeps tracking all other stuff except for my face (always on one or two shoulders). I suspected it had something to do with the coordinates, but I've checked them and they seem fine (mask_roi, hsv_roi, vis_roi). An example :
[image]

Can anybody point out my mistake ?

Comment: Hi @Ojtwist, I saw this here and was wondering if maybe you could take a gander at my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493008/using-opencv-detectmultiscale-to-find-my-face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to run your code (no module named video). I'm using OpenCV 2.4.4 and my solution to your problem is as follows:

1. Make sure your face is properly lit (no shadows, bright natural skin color, dark background helps a lot)
2. play with `hsv` values in `mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array((0., 60., 32.))`, `np.array((180., 255., 255.)))`. I'm using those: `np.array((0., 51., 89.))`, `np.array((17., 140., 255.))`

**Tip:**

you could make a window just for your mask so you can see how well it works

after: `cv2.namedWindow('camshift')` put `cv2.namedWindow('mask')`

and after: `mask = cv2.inRange...` put `cv2.imshow('mask', mask)` or `mask_roi`.

Comment: the video module is a standard python module given in opencv. You can find it by searching in your opencv folder (video.py). I'll look into your suggestions later on.

Comment: I played around with those values and it works better, though it also tracks my neck now :p. I'll see how to restrict the bounding box.