# Using webcam as a sensor

Tags: python, hardware, webcam, sensors

I have started playing Starcraft II recently and I come up with a problem that is more interesting for me now then the game itself.

There are 3 ways to control the camera in the game:

1. Keyboard keys [Up][Down][Left][Right]
2. Scroll the edge of the screen with a mouse
3. Hold the middle mouse button to scroll

I prefer the keyboard scroll because it is smooth. I don’t like the way the camera moves when you scroll with a mouse.

With the keyboard scroll there is a problem that your left hand is busy scrolling and it is hard to use other hotkeys. I wish I had one more hand to do the camera scrolling.

I also have a webcam on the top of my screen. I thought of an idea to use the webcam as a sensor.

Is there an easy way to distinguish colors or the orientation with the webcam? I see the implementation like: paint each side of a match in four colors, one for each direction: Up, Down, Left, Right. Put the match in the mouth and move in with the tongue Up, Down, Left and Right.

If the webcam could distinguish these colors it would a perfect joystick to do Up, Down, Left and Right moves.

I want to use it  in Starcraft II, but once implemented it can be used in other games and any other projects.

I can do some Python.

Are there any programmable solutions to turn a webcam into a sensor?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "match in the mouth"?

Comment: Yes, there are lots of solutions.
But you'll still have to implement a lot on your own. The fastest way would be to connect your application to a kinnect camera: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper and that will give you a quick way to distinguish movements.

Comment: "match in the mouth" is just an figurative idea. It can be anything with four sides and long.  http://www.clipartof.com/interior_wall_decor/details/Cartoon-Fire-Eater-Holding-A-Match-In-His-Mouth-Poster-Art-Print-1044389

Comment: By the way, I am not alone. People are thinking in the same direction, but with feet controller. And it is almost on the market! http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/289858283/stinky-the-gaming-footboard-step-up-your-game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper and get yourself some code.
Use the wrapper to distinguish movements (basics would be to measure one fram with another frame and calculage the direction where a certain mean_value(oldPixelArea, newPixelArea) and that would give you your controls.).

The next step would be to submit keystrokes to Starcraft which, on it's own.. is not allowed if i know blizzard well enough.
But yea you could use: https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/

If you don't own a kinnect camera (or don't want one).
You'd have to implement EVERYTHING on your own basically..
Everything from reading image frames (one by one), analyzing 3-dimensional movements OR just a selected area where the lightning can not differ to much and use that as a "fixing" point to read movements in directions.

Pygame can read webcam data, so that would be a good start:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/camera/CameraIntro.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check OpenCV which is a very good computer vision library. They have bindings for many languages including Python.

You will find several tutorials and code sample that will help you write a face detection/tracking software, for instance:

- [CamShift + Face detection in OpenCv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618183/camshift-face-detection-in-opencv)
- http://www.calebmadrigal.com/facial-detection-opencv-python/
- http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/face-detection-in-3-lines-of-code